# React state issue (a bad setState?) when trying to show a component composed with styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, styled-system

Now I am not entirely sure what confluence of things brought this issue to a head, but lets start with my minimal [reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-onclick-issue-with-nested-styled-components-react-aria-framer-motion-35dub?file=/src/App.tsx)

#### What am I trying to do

I want to show a styled element that is composed from various "inherited" members inside of a modal. Once the element is clicked, it will dismiss the modal.

#### Actual results

For some reason the element triggers it's `onClick` early, as soon as you click the button that is actually supposed to open the modal. It is only because it's a styled component (I think). **If I change the element from a `Para` to a normal `p`, it behaves correctly**.

I'm wondering, what can cause this? Is it that I nested too much? The error I get is

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Styled(Styled(styled.div))`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Styled(Styled(styled.div))`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're spreading ...rest in your Para styled-component.  Remove it from ./Para.js and it should work as expected